# Unable to set dhcp server on Ubuntu 20 desktop

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

On my Ubuntu 20 desktop machine, I am using Wifi for internet and hence my LAN interface is free. So I want to use it as a DHCP server interface.

```
eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b4:2e:19:c6:73:57  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 449  bytes 37227 (37.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 449  bytes 37227 (37.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.99  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::c148:f87a:baf:8027  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 90:cc:df:93:d7:08  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2324  bytes 222866 (222.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1903  bytes 348600 (348.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Following is my `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` :

```
INTERFACESv4="eno1"
INTERFACESv6=""
```

Following is my `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` :

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;

allow bootp;
allow booting;
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 10.0.0.100 10.0.0.200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option routers 10.0.0.1;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
#option root-path "/home/naveen/rootfs-arm64/“; #provided by boot.scr.img
}

host hikey {
hardware ethernet 34:29:8f:70:06:d0;
fixed-address 10.0.0.225;
#option root-path "/home/naveen/rootfs-arm64/“; #provided by boot.scr.img
}
```

Following is my `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

But I still get the error :

```
● isc-dhcp-server.service - ISC DHCP IPv4 server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/isc-dhcp-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-01-30 23:28:03 IST; 13s ago
       Docs: man:dhcpd(8)
    Process: 1606 ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec      CONFIG_FILE=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf;      if [ -f /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf ]; then CONFIG_FILE=/etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf; fi;      [ -e /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases ] || touc>
   Main PID: 1606 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 30 23:28:03 lab dhcpd[1606]:
Jan 30 23:28:03 lab dhcpd[1606]: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Jan 30 23:28:03 lab dhcpd[1606]:
Jan 30 23:28:03 lab dhcpd[1606]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Jan 30 23:28:03 lab dhcpd[1606]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Jan 30 23:28:03 lab dhcpd[1606]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Jan 30 23:28:03 lab dhcpd[1606]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Jan 30 23:28:03 lab dhcpd[1606]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
Jan 30 23:28:03 lab dhcpd[1606]:
Jan 30 23:28:03 lab dhcpd[1606]: exiting.
```

Comment: The interface eno1 has not any IP. Could you restart the network service to see if the interface will get an IP with accordance to /etc/network/interfaces ?

Comment: @JohnRonald :  Yeah that's a wierd thing that I also observed. I have restarted Ubuntu multiple times. When `/etc/network/interfaces/` is present, the `eno1` interface is not listed in the `ifconfig`. There seems some problem with the interface file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your eno1 interface. Since Ubuntu 20 uses netplan you find your config in /etc/netplan. There you should add something like:

```
    eno1:
        addresses:
        - 10.0.0.1/24
        dhcp4: false
```